# Постоянный вызов функции адаптера из главного класса android

Tags: android, android-threads

У меня есть список, в котором я хочу выделять элементы, для дальнейшей работы с ними. Этот список имеет адаптер в котором есть функция которая возвращает массив выделенных элементов. Но я не могу понять как постоянно вызывать эту функцию. Я так почитал что это нужно сделать в потоках, сделал функцию:

```
private void checkState()
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MessageCenter.this, ListAdapter.getChecked().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
```

и дальше вызываю ее в `onCreate()` и почему-то получаю ошибку:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

вообще какая у меня глобальная цель, постоянно мониторить массив с выделенными элементами и если в массиве есть что-то, то показывать кнопку на экране, а если ничего нету, то не показывать, вот как я это делаю:

```
checkState();

        Button deleteBtn = findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteGroup(ListAdapter.getChecked());
                recreate();
            }
        });
```

последний кусок кода находится в методе `onCreate()` и как можно увидеть из кода, я при создании активити вызываю функцию, но почему-то приложение упало. Я не могу понять в чем может быть проблема.

### UPDATE

Если я все правильно понял, у нас при длительном клике на элемент списки должна вызываться функция которая показывает или скрывает кнопку. Вот я сделал функцию:

```
public void checkState() {
        Button deleteBtn = findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

дальше вот как я все вызываю из адаптера:

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                if (message.isCan_delete()) {
                    holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.attachIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.tvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                MessageCenter messageCenter = new MessageCenter();
                messageCenter.checkState();
                setEditMode();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

но у меня вылетает ошибка:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
```

пробовал дебагером просмотреть что есть в функции на момент вызова, но ничего не получилось почему-то.

Comment: Ошибка из-за тоста - ему нужно создать `Handler`, а тому нужен `Looper`, а у Вас простой поток без лупера. Отвыкайте логировать код тостами - `Log` надёжнее.

Comment: а вообще моя задача решается при помощи потока, или нужно как-то по-другому это делать? потому-что я почему-то сразу в сторону потоков посмотрел, но не уверен что они мне подойдут

Comment: Мониторить что-то в цикле - не лучшее решение и применяется когда совсем без вариантов. Не знаю как там в модных архитектурах, наверное  слушатель надо применять. Но общий смысл в том, что адаптер после изменения чекбокса проверяет размер списка и посылает сигнал активности что нужно показать/скрыть эту кнопку. Посылает - в смысле  вызывает соответствующий метод в активности напрямую или через листенер, или через хандлер, может ещё как-то... Но в любом случае событие не мониторится, а инициируется самим изменением состояния.

Comment: @woesss, давайте я попытаюсь систематизировать то что я понял из того что вы сказали. Вот у меня ситуация, когда на активити есть список, по умолчанию элементы которые зависят от длинного нажатия на элемент списка скрыты, но вот мы делаем длинное нажатие на элемент списка и у нас что-то скрывается и что-то показывается, и дальше если у нас выбран один чекбокс, мы вызываем функцию в активности для показывания новых элементов на экране, я правильно все понял, или опять что-то не так интерпретировал?

Comment: Когда кликнули по чекбоксу и в результате список чёкнутых опустел или наоборот стал не пустым - посылаем сигнал активности: "покажи/спрячь ту самую кнопку (`deleteBtn` как я понял)". То есть событие вызывается в листенере чекбокса.

Comment: @woesss, сейчас обновлю вопрос, так как у меня лезет ошибка которую я не могу понять.

Comment: Прочтите мой последний коммент ещё раз. И ху из `MessageCenter`???  Если это активность, то запомните, а лучше запишите))) - ссылку на активити можно передать, но ни при каких обстоятельствах активность **нельзя создавать оператором `new`** . Получите просто пустышку не имеющую никакого отношения к Вашей реальной `Activity`.

Comment: `MessageCenter` это там где висит кнопка которую я хочу скрыть, я думал что можно вызывать методы таким образом, но почему-то приложение падает, я когда чекаю чекбокс то вызываю метод для показа кнопки, но что-то походу не так делаю

Comment: @woesss, вроде как решил проблему, но студия советует не ставить объявление кнопки в статик, но без статик у меня метод не видится адаптером

Comment: И правильно ругается - потому что Вы не последовали моему совету и не разобрались в отличии статик и не статик, и классов и объектов. Без понимания этой темы объяснять Вам почему так делать нехорошо дело неблагодарное.

Comment: @woesss, а в какую сторону хоть копать? я то не против разобраться но не знаю в какую сторону смотреть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих мучений у меня все-таки получилось сделать то что я хотел. Какая стояла цель: у меня есть список сообщений(входящие, исходящие и черновики) с которым я хотел сделать функцию группового удаления. Группой удалять можно, но проблема была в чем: выделялись элементы списка чекбоксами, которые появлялись у каждого элемента списка после длительного нажатия на него. Но вопрос в том как его удалять, пришлось сделать кнопку которая при нажатии на нее отсылает на сервер массив из id сообщений. Но получается что кнопка висела постоянно на экране и это было не очень красиво. Я сделал так что, адаптер постоянно при изменении состояния чекбокса, вызывает функцию из главного класса для показывания или скрывания кнопки. Вот что у меня в итоге есть в адаптере:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    set.add(message.getId());
                    MessageCenter.checkState(1);
                } else {
                    set.remove(message.getId());
                    if (getChecked().isEmpty()) {
                        editMode = false;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

в адаптере по умолчанию в `onBindViewHolder` стоит такая штука:

```
MessageCenter.checkState(0);
```

и вот что у меня в главном классе:

```
public static void checkState(int k) {
    if (k == 0) {
        deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (k == 1) {
        deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

ну и объявление кнопки:

```
public static Button deleteBtn;
```

студии не нравится что кнопка помечена `static` но по-другому у меня не видит метод в активити.

> Теперь что у меня получается: делаем длительное нажатие на элемент
>   списка, в моем случае это письмо, сразу пропадает дата прихода письма,
>   и на ее месте появляется чекбокс для выбора письма и добавления в
>   массив, после того как выбран хотя-бы один элемент списка, сразу
>   появляется кнопка для удаления, если потом везде снять выделение то
>   кнопка пропадает и пропадает чекбокс, и все становится как вначале,
>   для повторной попытки удалить несколько писем нужно опять делать
>   длительное нажатие на элемент списка.

Если кто-то знает как исправить или улучшить мой код, то буду очень рад услышать ваши предложения. Надеюсь что мой способ поможет таким же начинающим как и я)

Comment: Секцию `default` в `switch` можно опустить

Comment: это из-за того что в bindViewHolder есть постоянная отправка в функцию 0, что дает команду убрать кнопку?

Comment: Точнее секцию `case 0` можно опустить)

Comment: Да и вообще `switch` тут лучше на `if/else` заменить

Comment: обновил ответ, вроде работает