# Как исправить мой метод где используется статический параметр android?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть список созданный на основе `RecyclerView` этот список имеет адаптер и главный класс где потом вызывается для дальнейшей работы. Так получается что мне нужно получать данные из адаптера в главном классе. Для решения этой задачи у меня есть метод в главном классе который вызывается из адаптера. Но пока по не очень понятным причинам, метод в главном классе должен быть статическим, чтобы из адаптера его можно было вызвать. Студии не очень нравится то что я использую виджеты такие как кнопка и layout с пометкой статик в этом методе, и она мне пишет:

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a
>   memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)

все с этой проблемой сталкивались, но у меня она впервые. Для работы класса и активити в целом это вроде пока не мешает,но чувствую что будет мешать в скором времени. Вот переменные статик:

```
public static LinearLayout linearLayout;
public static ImageButton deleteBtn;
```

вот метод где я их использую:

```
public static void checkState(int k) {
        if (k == 0) {
            deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (k == 1) {
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

в моем предыдущем вопросе - [Постоянный вызов функции адаптера из главного класса android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/890840/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-android) мне посоветовали почитать про идентификаторы доступа и про эту ошибку в целом, что я и сделал. Что я понял из всего прочитанного, что переменные с таким идентификатором живут меньше чем обычное активити и это может привести к утечке памяти. Но я все-равно не смог пока понять, как исправить мою ситуацию. Надеюсь что моя проблема имеет решение, просто я его не вижу)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете дабавить слушатель для вашего адаптера

```
//StateListener.java
public interface StateListener() {
    void check(int k);
}

//Создание адаптера, внутри фрагмента 
Adapter a = new Adapter();
final Button finalDeleteBtn = deleteBtn; 
final LinearLayout finalLinearLayout = linearLayout; 
a.setListener((MainActivity)getActivity());

//внутри адаптера
private StateListener stateListener;

public setListener(StateListener listener) {
    this.stateListener = listener;
}


//там где сейчас вызывается статический метод, этот код находится внутри адаптера
stateListener.check(k);
```

реализуйте в главном Acitivity созданный интерфейс

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements StateListener
```

Comment: единственное что у меня пока получилось, так это создать интерфейс)) у меня адаптер в отдельном классе, и к его методу мне нужно получить доступ. Создание адаптера в главном классе не имеет смысла)

Comment: А где создается Recycler и его адаптер?

Comment: у меня возможно все криво сделано)) есть активити которое построено на основе `navigationdrawer` и там есть контент который висит в фрагментах которые привязаны к пунктам меню, и там, есть фрагмент где создается этот список, и вот там используется адаптер) сложная и кривая система я думаю

Comment: где находится ваш статический класс?

Comment: статического класса у меня нет, тот метод что в вопросе находится в классе который является контейнером для фрагмента

Comment: я изменил ответ, попробуйте еще

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84330/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-shokhrukh-ismoilov).